# Error while uploading apk file to developer console

Tags: android, google-play, apk, publish

I tried to upload apk file to google developer console but an error occurs. Apk file size is 77 mb, I tried different variants to fix it, clean and rebuild project, cleared browser cache and other but nothing.  Maybe someone who has faced a similar problem can help me?

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: Could not understand file.

Comment: What do your app do ? because 77mo is big. Did you signed your apk ?

Comment: Yes, I have signed my apk. The size is so big because it contains bundled realm database.

Comment: No details about the error ? just "could not understand" ? Have you try on an other computer ?

Comment: No details, only this message. I did not try on another computer. I don't think that it depends on computer.

Comment: I just try to help you. That's a weird error. Sorry, I can't help you T_T

Comment: Maybe something wrong with apk file or Android Studio works incorrect

Comment: What version of android studio are you using? Try invalidating the cache and restart

Comment: I'm using v.2.1.2. Yes I have restarted android studio